# most often vs the most often the smaller one chases the bigger one

Tags: word-choice

"The funny thing about these dogs is that the smaller one most often chases the bigger one." [so whenever they meet in the park that's how they play]

I feel like leaving out "the" before "most" is the more natural choice here. If so, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Your sense is correct. (By the way, if the meaning is one that contrasts each dog’s chasing the other,  traditionalists would prefer ***more** often chases* because there are only two alternatives and they’d reserve *most* for three or more.)

One *would* use *the* in constructions like

> That’s perhaps **the most often** quoted of Mark Twain’s witticisms,

which can be paraphrased as

> That’s one of Mark Twain’s witticisms and may be the one quoted more than any other.